# How to do semantic analysis from POS tag?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

suppose sentence is, "Vehicle does not start in cold weather and need to change windshield blades." I'm interested to find out what part of car is affected, and what is the reason for that. From above sentence, we can not infer that windshield blades does not start. In addition single sentence can contain multiple car parts. How to tackle this problem?

Comment: you are interested in 'textual entailment'. have a look here: http://www.google.com/cse?cx=011664571474657673452%3A4w9swzkcxiy&cof=FORID%3A0&q=textual+entailment#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=textual%20entailment&gsc.page=1

Comment: tell us about your data, the scope of your system, and what has been tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, above problem can be easily solved with the help of Stanford dependencies, so we can use Stanford coreNLP for that.